# how to create chain of properties javascript?

Tags: javascript

How would I create something like this: `main.something.word`

```
main = {something: 'test'}
//This results in main.something returning "test"
```

How would I make `main.something.word` also return test?

```
//I tried doing this and it didn't work.
main = {something: 'test' word: 'test'}
```

Comment: You cannot have `something` be a string and an object with a `word` property at the same time. Which one do you want?

Comment: Possibility and semantics aside, why is this even necessary? What's the usecase?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
main = {something: { word:'test' } };
console.log(main.something.word);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that: a value cannot be a primitive string and object at the same time.

However, you can use the feature whereby the context makes JavaScript convert a value to string (by calling the `toString` method).

Here is one of the many ways to use that behaviour:

```js
var main = {
    something: Object.assign('test', {
        word: Object.assign('another test', {
            next: 'deepest'
        })
    })
};
    
console.log( main.something + ', ' +
             main.something.word + ', ' +
             main.something.word.next );
```

The values in the nested object are not primitive strings, but `String` objects: `Object.assign` will turn the first argument into an object, a `String` object in this case. That object is given an additional property specified in the second argument to `Object.assign`, for storing the nested value. A `String` object (which is not the same thing as a string primitive), has a `toString` method that gets called here because the object is concatenated with a `+`.